# Access methods of instantiated class stored in ArrayList

Tags: processing

I'm a beginner in Java (I have a JS background) and I'm trying to do the exercise at the end of Chapter 1 of the [nature of code](http://natureofcode.com/book/chapter-1-vectors/#the-ecosystem-project) book.

What I'm trying to do is generate a list of instances.
I've had a very hard time understanding how Java manages classes and instances so please bear with me.

What I do have now :

- Create ArrayList
- Select random classname from list of strings
- Instantiate that class with Class.forName, getConstructor and newInstance
- Store instance in ArrayList
- Iterate on ArrayList
- Call method

Here's the code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.reflect.*;

List < Object > bugs = new ArrayList < Object > ();

String[] bugList = {
    "Bug",
        "Fly",
        "Bee"
};

void setup() {
    String currentClass;

    int bugLength = bugList.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        int chosenClass = getRandNumber(0, bugLength - 1);
        currentClass = bugList[chosenClass];

        bugs.add(loadClass(currentClass));
    }
}

public Object loadClass(String chosenClass) {
    String className;

    Class <? > cl = null;
    Constructor[] cons = null;
    Object instance = null;

    className = this.getClass().getName() + "$";

    try {
        cl = Class.forName(className + chosenClass);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        //
    }

    try {
        cons = cl.getDeclaredConstructors();
    } catch (Exception e) {}

    try {
        instance = cons[0].newInstance(new Object[] {
            this
        });
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        //
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        //
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        //
    }


    return instance;
}

void draw() {
    for (int i = 0; i < bugs.size(); i++) {
        bugs.get(i).update();
    }
}

class Bug {
    // Snip

    public Bug() {
        // Snip
    }

    public void update() {
        // Snip
    }

    public void render() {
        // Snip
    }
}

class Fly extends Bug {
    public Fly() {
        // Snip
    }
}

class Bee extends Bug {
    public Bee() {
        // Snip
    }
}
```

And the problem is in the draw function as I suppose it tries to access a method named "update" from an Object and not from my instance.

Would it be possible to explictly cast the object to the correct type when accessed?
Or is there some way to store different instance types and have their names directly?

Or, as I saw mentioned elsewhere for someone's piece of code, am I trying to be too dynamic for Java?

Comment: Please provide the relevant code in the question. Do not rely on external sites to provide the code.

Comment: This is rather odd code. Processing has no explicit visibility model, so marking things as "public" is curious to say the least. Doing lots of reflection gets even stranger; practically speaking you just want your `Bug`s to come with a static `.create` factory method, thus also removing the need to assume you're on a JVM (not every Processing interpreter comes with a full Java stack)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, yes I figured I was doing something quite wrong.
I get the factory method but how would you store the instances?

Comment: Processing does offer "native" support for the ArrayList and supports generics syntax, so you could just maintain a list of instances with `ArrayList<Bug> instances = new ArrayList<Bug>()` and use `.add` and `.remove` for list manipulation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explicitly cast the objects to `Bug` prior to calling `update`

*HOWEVER*

If you know that all of the objects in the `bugs` list will be sub classes of `Bug` then you should probably change `List<Object> bugs` to be `List<Bug> bugs`. This way you will be able to call `update()` with no issue (also if you pass the list to other areas of code then the other code can use the list as a list of `Bug`s instead of objects). In order to make this work, you will have to perform the cast to `Bug` inside of `loadClass()` and return an instance of `Bug` instead of `Object`.

Comment: Thanks for your help.
That's what I should have done but I realised I was complicating things too much and scrapped all the reflection part :)